# Proving this divisibility

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, divisibility

I am stuck with this problem and have no idea where to begin. I assume it will end up using Fermat's little theorem, but I am not sure.

**Prove if p is a prime and p > 2, then** $6|p^4 - 2017*p^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p=3$ then $p^2-2017$ even number and $6\mid p^2(p^2-2017)$.

If $p>3$ then $p= 6k +1 \text { or } 6k-1$. Then $p^2\equiv 1 \pmod{6}$. Hence $p^2 - 2017 \equiv 1 -2017 \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$ and for all cases:

$$6 \mid p^2(p^2-2017)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- the RHS is the difference of two odd numbers since $p$ is an odd prime;
- a prime $p \gt 3$ is congruent to $\pm 1 \bmod 3\,$, so $p^2 \equiv1\equiv 2017 \pmod 3\,$.